How to build a HW1F tree for SOFR?
I have previously built a HW1F trinomial tree (following the HW paper), and I manage to calibrate sigma(t) to swaptions and to price some derivatives. I discretise the tree quarterly (LIBOR3M).
However, I wonder how would this fit into a SOFR world. Would I have to propagate SOFR rate on a daily basis? Just for argument sake let’s assume I’m pricing a callable range accrual swap, with the range on SOFR itself.
StudentK.
